# blackhole attack splittingobject error

Tags: networking, simulator, ns2

i too have same problem.
please provide a clear solution for me...
following error is obtained when i run blackhole.tcl file.

```
ns: _o108 blackhole: 
    (_o108 cmd line 1)
    invoked from within
"_o108 cmd blackhole"
    invoked from within
"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
set cls [$self info class]
global errorInfo
set savedInfo $errorInfo
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
    (procedure "_o108" line 2)
    (SplitObject unknown line 2)
    invoked from within
"_o108 blackhole"
```

Answer (score 0):

Valid examples for the "2005-2013 blackholeaodv code" are : blackholeaodv2005-examples-3-Aug2015.tar.gz

Link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNUmJGd0ZyNUhvVFU/view?usp=sharing